# Lawn top dressing - how much and how long does the grass need to get through?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair, topsoil

I have a very low spot near a pathway I just built and a pile of soil that resulted from the excavation of the soil. I want to put the soil over the grass that is there, but I would like to know the answers to following questions:

- Is it a good idea?
- How long it will take the grass to get through, especially now that is very warm?
- How much soil to put over?
- Should I do this over just mowed grass or over longer grown grass?

In general, I have some lower spots which are not bald to say so (no grass) but where I would add soil just to make the spot level.

Update: picture showing the area, left side of that path

[image]

Comment: Hi MiniMe! Can you post a few pictures of this area for us please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two weeks later after lots of rain and adding soil then 1" of gardening soil and grass seeds and then another 1" of gardening soil

[image]

Note: the first picture was taken shortly after I installed the path
The second picture two weeks after seeding

Answer (score 4):

If the grass is in active growth (so, right now, northern hemisphere, where it's raining from time to time or irrigated) 1/4" (6-7mm) every couple of weeks is fairly safe. Every week is *probably* safe, but *might* be pushing it.

If it's not actively growing, you have to wait for growth.

The point is to NOT "bury" the grass - you want the applied soil to have grass sticking through it from the time it's applied, just having some extra soil around the base of the stems. If you add enough to bury it, you make a whole host of problems.

So, mow the grass first, it will stand up slightly better.